# Bash creating csv from values

Tags: sql, bash, csv

I'm trying to create a csv in my bash script from some values I'm getting from another non-csv file. 
The problem I see is that the values have commas(,) in them.

The csv file wrong because of that (the values with commas in them are 2 or more different values now)
Is there any way to get rid of that problem or any other way to build a csv in a bash script. I can create any other files too, it just needs to be compatible with standard sql import.

Thanks

Comment: It is probably better to use Perl or Python and its CSV modules. This is the safest.

Comment: Do the fields containing commas have quotes around them?

Comment: Show your incoming data, and what you want the output csv to look like.

Answer (score 0):

I now added quotation marks before and after every value and it works great. The csv looks like it should.